# How to send email notifications to a email group using AWS SNS?

Tags: amazon-sns

I am working on a task to send email notifications to a group of users from AWS SNS. I have created a topic and tested the notifications by sending it to my email. But now I want to send these email notifications to a group which contains at least 10 15 email IDs. 
How to send email notifications to a group or email alias using AWS SNS ?

Comment: Have you validated that group in SES in that same region?

Comment: @prabhat I am not using SES service. Just trying to push email notifications to a company group from SNS topic. I am also able to send it for a single email ID but not to a group.

Answer (score 4):

Amazon SNS sends notifications to Email alias by configuring it in the SNS Topic Subscription. I found out the problem with the Email alias of my org which was not allowing the push notifications from AWS.

I verified it by creating a email group in googlegroups.com and then allow anyone to push emails to this group and there I go. All the recipients in my googlegroup started receiving notifications from AWS SNS topic.

Make sure to check the filters/restrictions in your organization's email alias. If the email alias does not allow the push notifications/emails from AWS then you will not receive the email notifications even after configuring the topic subscription.